# Insert into table from dynamic lists

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using dynamic method to create table and then insert values into it. There are two lists that dynamically filled from different files and these lists could be increased or decreased in count as well as the values are changing every time. My problem here I managed to create the table with its fields dynamically but I still have some issues inserting values into it. here is my code:

```
f = open(filepath,"r")
pluginoutput= f.read()
pluginoptojson = json.loads(pluginoutput)
columnsnames = (pluginoptojson["columns"])
countcolumns = len(pluginoptojson["columns"])
count = 0
lst = []
for name in columnsnames:
    if count < countcolumns:
        lst.append(str(name))
        count +=1

lst.append("caseid")
table_name = "test2"
createsqltable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """ + table_name + " (" + " VARCHAR(50),".join(lst) + " VARCHAR(50))"
print createsqltable
c.execute(createsqltable)
conn.commit()

#c.close()
#conn.close()
#gc.collect()


rowsvalue = (pluginoptojson["rows"])

for row in rowsvalue:
    lst2 =[]
    rowelementscount = len(row)
    for value in row:
        lst2.append(str(value))
    lst2.append("test")
    insert_intotable = "INSERT INTO "  + table_name + "(" + ",".join(lst) + ") VALUES (" + ",".join(lst2) +")"
    print insert_intotable
    c.execute(insert_intotable)
    conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
gc.collect()
```

the file content as an example is :

```
{"lines": [[2, 12121, 33, 44, "ff"], [2, 786, 33, 66, "ww"]], "columns": ["id", "testnumber", "size", "gnumber", "filenname"]}
```

the print out of interesting values int table is :

```
INSERT INTO test8(id,testnumber,size,gnumber,filenname) VALUES (2,786,33, 66,ww,test)
```

the error I'm getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "pp.py", line 50, in 
>           c.execute(insert_intotable)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
>           self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>           raise errorclass, errorvalue
>       _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'ww,test)' at line 1")

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You close the cursor and the connection then you try your INSERT statement...

Comment: yeah you are right and I edit it but I still have syntax error.!

Comment: `ww` and `test` need to be strings. You should be using parametrized queries. Your design is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks given untrusted input.

Comment: I have converted all of them into string but now luck and thanks for the security hint.